# NHibernate Session.Query<>, column list?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

We have some code written which depends on working with the `IQueryable` instances, so I suppose we are stuck with having to use `ISession.Query<>()`.

In one particular case I would like to only partially hydrate the DBOs and exclude certain columns from the SELECT statement which NHibernate will generate.
Is it possible to achieve that while using `Query<>`?

Alternatively, is it possible to somehow go from `ICriteria` to `IQueryable`? *(I think for `ICriteria` it is possible to achieve what I need by using Projections?)*

Comment: Some addition information can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881410/how-to-fill-just-required-properties-of-entity-fluentnhibernate

Answer (score 1):

Projections are supported in `IQueryable` as well. Syntax should be like this:

```
var query = session.Query<Employee>();
var list = query.Select(s => new Employee
    {
        FirstName = s.FirstName,
        LastName = s.LastName,
        ...
     })
     .ToList();
```

The *new Employee* could be even some DTO...

Some basic info about `QueryOver` projection API:

- [16.6. Projections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections)